# How to animate Image png with openlayers3

Tags: javascript, html, image, openlayers-3

I need to implement a function with openlayers-3.
Description:There are a series of images .png. I need to play them like a animation.I set the image source as ImageStatic,but When I set the current image visible is false ,it doesn't work. the visible property seems like not work.
Code:

```js
  var extent = [0, 0, 418, 600];
        var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
            code: 'xkcd-image',
            units: 'pixels',
            extent: extent
        });

        var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [
              new ol.layer.Tile({
                  source: new ol.source.OSM()
              }),
              new ol.layer.Group({
                  layers: [
                      new ol.layer.Image({
                          source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
                              url: 'http://localhost:2265/images3/test2.png',
                              projection: projection,
                              imageExtent: extent,
                          })
                      }),
                     new ol.layer.Image({
                         source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
                             url: 'http://localhost:2265/images2/test1.png',
                             projection: projection,
                             imageExtent: extent,
                         })
                     })
                  ]
              })
            ],
            target: 'map',
            view: new ol.View({
                projection: projection,
                center: ol.extent.getCenter(extent),
                zoom: 2,
                maxZoom: 8
            })
        });
        var layers = map.getLayers().getArray();
        var frame = 1;
        setInterval(function () {
            layers[frame].setVisible = false;
            frame = (frame + 1) % 2;
            layers[frame].setVisible = true;            
        },500);
```

Comment: I need an animation with a series of images

Comment: Is this JavaScript code?

Comment: Yes.Is there any problems?

Comment: I wanted to confirm before editing your tags. This way other JS coders will see it. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

map.layers[[1](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/flight-animation.html?q=animation)] is a group, to get the image layers try:

```
var layers = map.getLayers().getArray()[1].getLayers().getArray();
```

You can also do 'real' animation by rendering directly to the canvas:

[http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/flight-animation.html?q=animation)
http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/flight-animation.html

Comment: No.The examples are not what I want.The condition is  we need to play the cloud chart by images png we rendered by our meteorological data

Comment: While the problem has sovled.First, I should get the image layers by "var layers = map.getLayers().getArray()[1].getLayers().getArray();". Second,  It  should be  "layers[0].R.visible = false" or "layers[0].setVisible(false)"